# Weil restriction of abelian schemes along finite étale (resp. finite locally free) morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-schemes, abelian-varieties, algebraic-spaces

Q: Is there a simple proof of the fact that the Weil restriction of an abelian scheme along a finite étale morphism is an abelian scheme ?

Details: Let $S$ be a scheme and $f:S'\rightarrow S$ a finite étale morphism. Let $A/S'$ be an abelian scheme. Then the following argument shows that the Weil restriction $\mathfrak{R}_{S'/S}$(A) (see section 7.6 of the book *Néron Models* by Bosch, Lütkebohmert and Raynaud) which a priori is just an fppf sheaf of abelian groups on $Sch/S$ is representable by an abelian scheme over $S$:

1) <strike>Theorem 1.5 of M. Olsson's paper *Hom stacks and restriction of scalars* (Duke Math. J. 134 (2006), 139-164.) gives a general criterion for a Weil restriction to be representable by an algebraic space, which applies here to show that $\mathfrak{R}_{S'/S}(A)$ is representable by an algebraic space over $S$.</strike>

By passing to a Galois cover, $\mathfrak{R}_{S'/S}(A)$ decomposes as a product of abelian schemes, so is representable by an algebraic space over $S$.

2) The arguments used to prove Proposition 7.6.5 (f) and (h) of *Néron Models* show that $\mathfrak{R}_{S'/S}(A)$ is smooth and proper as an algebraic space. Moreover the formation of the Weil restriction commutes with base change and its fibers are connected by Proposition A.5.9 of the book *Pseudo-reductive Groups* by Conrad,Gabber and Prasad.

3) By 1) and 2), $\mathfrak{R}_{S'/S}(A)$ is an abelian algebraic space in the sense of Section I.1 of the book *Degeneration of abelian varieties* by Chai and Faltings. By Theorem 1.9 of loc. cit. (due to Raynaud) it is actually an abelian scheme.

The "problem" with this proof is that 3) is a relatively delicate result. Of course, if $A$ is projective over $S$, the Weil restriction is automatically a scheme and we can do without 1) and 3). However, the question of when an abelian scheme is projective over the base is subtle in general: it is known to hold over a noetherian normal base but the argument is a key part of the proof of 3) anyway.

My motivation is to understand the push-forward functoriality of Deligne 1-motives over a base, and I would like to be able to consider general abelian schemes over general base schemes.

> 1) Does anyone know a simpler proof ?
>
> 2) If one assumes only that $S'/S$ is finite locally free, is  $\mathfrak{R}_{S'/S}(A)$ (which might not be proper anymore) still a scheme ?

Comment: Dear Simon, Can you check this by etale descent?  Namely, if you let $S''$ over $S$ be a Galois etale cover lying over $S'$, and pull-back the restriction of scalars to $S''$, then it should just a product of the appropriate number of copies of the original $A$.  So after this etale pull-back we *do* get an abelian scheme.  Hopefully descent now applies to conclude that the restriction of scalars itself was an ab. scheme.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: @Emerton: this shows that the restriction is an algebraic space, but how do you prove that it is a scheme ? Indeed, I see that 1) is overkill, even in the case where $S'/S$ is only finite locally free. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @Simon: Cf. Murre.

Comment: Do you seek a proof that avoids algebraic spaces entirely? That seems unlikely to be possible, and if one is going to be using algebraic spaces then the Faltings-Chai proof is an extremely natural one (building off of the normal case in a clever way). For your purposes with Deligne 1-motives, is it a problem to work throughout with algebraic spaces (which are well-suited to questions related to quotients in algebraic geometry)?

Comment: @Jason Starr: which paper of Murre are you referring to ? Is it the Bourbaki seminar on unramified functors ?

@nosr: because of Raynaud's theorem, most of the algebraic spaces (e.g. semi-abelian algebraic spaces of constant rank) I need are schemes. On the other hand, I can work with algebraic spaces, since I am ultimately interested in the complex of sheaves and the associated objects in triangulated categories of mixed motives. It is more a matter of not being familiar with the technology.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X \to S'$ be a smooth projective morphism, and $S' \to S$ a finite étale morphism.

The Weil restriction $Y \to S$ of $X \to S'$ is a closed subscheme of the scheme of morphisms $S' \to X$ on $S$, which is projective; hence it is projective (this is Grothendieck's original construction).

Let us show that $Y \to S$ is again smooth. Construction of the Weil restriction is étale local on $S$; hence we may assume that $S' = S_1 \sqcup \dots \sqcup S_m$ is a disjoint union of $m$ copies $S_1, \dots, S_m$ of $S$. Call $X_i$ the restriction of $X$ to $S_i$. It follows readily from the definition that $Y \to S$ is the product $X_1 \times_S \dots \times_S X_m$, and this proves smoothness.

If $X \to S'$ is an abelian scheme, the group scheme structure of $X \to S'$ induces a group scheme structure on $Y \to S$, and this completes the proof.

Comment: Doesn't this work only for projective abelian schemes?

Comment: @Ricky: Cf. Murre.